# Delete an .EXE application remotely

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, exe, uninstallation

when the application is from .msi or .msu it's easy to uninstall them from a remote computer using WMI, but WMI only works on Microsoft based applications (.msi, .msu). I can't find a way to uninstall an exe based app remotely without using invoke, I try to not use it because this will be used by many people and on many computers, it's disabled, I can enable it for me but not for everyone (I'm an intern :D)

this is the code that I have for .exe but it's not remote

```
cmd.exe /c "$($app.meta.Attributes["UninstallString"]) /S"
```

while this is a remote msi, msu uninstall line

```
$Application = Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -ComputerName $ComputerName | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $Name}  #choose the object, this will be the app that we will delete
if ($Application) {
  $Application.Uninstall()
```

any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem with `Invoke-Command` is. You can run the command on many computers in parallel, by passing an _array_ of computer names.

Comment: the issue is that the company I work in has disabled that command, I can enable it for me but I can't do it for everyone that is going to use the app @zett42

thanks for the help you've given this days, you answered 2 of my questions already :D

Comment: Maybe you can use a [logon script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn789196(v=ws.11)#to-assign-user-logon-scripts)?

Comment: will have a look, thanks